# How to split one column into multiple columns in Pandas using regular expression?

Tags: python, pandas

For example, if I have a home address like this:

`71 Pilgrim Avenue, Chevy Chase, MD`

in a column named 'address'. I would like to split it into columns 'street', 'city', 'state', respectively.

What is the best way to achieve this using Pandas ?

I have tried `df[['street', 'city', 'state']] = df['address'].findall(r"myregex")`.

But the error I got is `Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable`.

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) by regex `,\s+` (`,` and one or more whitespaces):

```
#borrowing sample from `Allen`
df[['street', 'city', 'state']] = df['address'].str.split(',\s+', expand=True)
print (df)
                              address id             street          city  \
0  71 Pilgrim Avenue, Chevy Chase, MD  a  71 Pilgrim Avenue   Chevy Chase   
1         72 Main St, Chevy Chase, MD  b         72 Main St   Chevy Chase   

  state  
0    MD  
1    MD
```

And if need remove column `address` add [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
df[['street', 'city', 'state']] = df['address'].str.split(',\s+', expand=True)
df = df.drop('address', axis=1)
print (df)
  id             street         city state
0  a  71 Pilgrim Avenue  Chevy Chase    MD
1  b         72 Main St  Chevy Chase    MD
```

Comment: u know what, this `split` with `expand` param is terrific, wish I could upvote this one 100 times

Answer (score 3):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'address': {0: '71 Pilgrim Avenue, Chevy Chase, MD',
      1: '72 Main St, Chevy Chase, MD'},
     'id': {0: 'a', 1: 'b'}})
#if your address format is consistent, you can simply use a split function.
df2 = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.address.str.split(',').tolist(),columns=['street', 'city', 'state']))
df2 = df2.applymap(lambda x: x.strip())
```

Comment: Thank you Allen ! Great code :) The reason I didn't use `split` because I would like to remove the whitespace in the string as well. Is there a way to achieve that from split ?