# Pandas parsing excel file all in column A

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have a wireless radio readout that basically dumps all of the data into one column (column 'A') a of a spreadsheet (.xlsx). Is there anyway to parse the twenty plus columns into a dataframe for pandas? This is example of the data that is in column A of the excel file:

```
DSP ALLMSINFO:SECTORID=0,CARRIERID=0;
Belgium351G
+++    HUAWEI        2020-04-03 10:04:47 DST 
O&M    #4421590
%%/*35687*/DSP ALLMSINFO:SECTORID=0,CARRIERID=0;%%
RETCODE = 0  Operation succeeded

Display Information of All MSs-
------------------------------
Sector ID  Carrier ID  MSID            MSSTATUS  MSPWR(dBm)  DLCINR(dB)  ULCINR(dB)  DLRSSI(dBm)  ULRSSI(dBm)  DLFEC  ULFEC  DLREPETITIONFATCTOR  ULREPETITIONFATCTOR  DLMIMOFLAG  BENUM  NRTPSNUM  RTPSNUM  ERTPSNUM  UGSNUM  UL PER for an MS(0.001)  NI Value of the Band Where an MS Is Located(dBm)  DL Traffic Rate for an MS(byte/s)  UL Traffic Rate for an MS(byte/s)
0          0           0011-4D10-FFBA  Enter     -2          29          27          -56          -107         21     20     0                    0                    MIMO B      2      0         0        0         0       0                        -134                                              158000                             46000
0          0           501F-F63B-FB3B  Enter     13          27          28          -68          -107         21     20     0                    0                    MIMO A      2      0         0        0         0       0                        -134                                              12                                 8
```

Basically I just want to parse this data and have the table in a dataframe. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you attach an example xlsx file? I'm struggling to see if Sector ID and Carrier ID are different columns or not

Comment: They are different columns. I can't because allowing the real MSID columns would be a security violation for my company. These are dummy data entries.

Comment: What is the relevance of the column A here?

Comment: All of this data is in column A. That is how the radio export spits it out. I want to be able to split the columns correctly (as shown) for a pandas dataframe.

Comment: So they are different columns but they are all one column? I have added code that will work if they are different columns within excel. If that's wrong you could still use it to read in as a dataframe containing only one column then split that using the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43730422/how-to-split-one-column-into-multiple-columns-in-pandas-using-regular-expression

Comment: That splitting is what I was looking for. I believe that will solve my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Also have fun with the radio station! That at the moment is my dream career haha

Answer (score 0):

You could try pandas read excel

```
    df = pd.read_excel(filename, skip_rows=9)
```

This assumes we want to ignore the first 9 rows that don't make up the dataframe! Docs here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Answer (score 0):

Load the excel file and split the column on the spaces.

A problem may occur with "DLMIMOFLAG" because it has a space in the data and this will cause it to be split over two columns. It's optional whether this is acceptable or if the columns are merged back together afterwards.

Add the header manually rather than load it, otherwise all the spaces in the header will confuse the loading & splitting routines.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Start on the first data row - row 10
# Make sure pandas knows that only data is being loaded by using 
# header=None
df = pd.read_excel('radio.xlsx', skiprows=10, header=None)
```

This gives a dataframe that is only data, all held in one column.

To split these out, make sure pandas has a reference to the first column with `df.iloc[:,0]`, split the column based on spaces with `str.split()` and inform pandas the output will be a numpy list `values.tolist()`.

Together this looks like:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[:,0].str.split().values.tolist())
```

Note the example given has an extra column because of the space in "DLMIMOFLAG" causing it to be split over two columns. This will be referred to as "DLMIMOFLAG_A" and "DLMIMOFLAG_B".

Now add on the column headers.
Optionally create a list first.

```
column_names = ["Sector ID", "Carrier ID", "MSID", "MSSTATUS", "MSPWR(dBm)", "DLCINR(dB)", "ULCINR(dB)",
                "DLRSSI(dBm)", "ULRSSI(dBm)", "DLFEC", "ULFEC", "DLREPETITIONFATCTOR", "ULREPETITIONFATCTOR",
                "DLMIMOFLAG_A", "DLMIMOFLAG_B", "BENUM", "NRTPSNUM", "RTPSNUM", "ERTPSNUM", "UGSNUM",
                "UL PER for an MS(0.001)", "NI Value of the Band Where an MS Is Located(dBm)", 
                "DL Traffic Rate for an MS(byte/s)", "UL Traffic Rate for an MS(byte/s)",]
df2.columns = column_names
```

This gives the output as a full dataframe with column headers.

```
Sector ID Carrier ID MSID           MSSTATUS
0            0       0011-4D10-FFBA Enter
0            0       501F-F63B-FB3B Enter
```